# Erro de permissão em servidor

Tags: php, servidor, permissões

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/PaperCutMF15-Pet Center Comercio e Participacoes S.A., BR.license): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/ecoprintq.com.br/public_html/portal/intranet/classes/Upload.php on line 40

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpy3gdPW' to 'upload/PaperCutMF15-Pet Center Comercio e Participacoes S.A., BR.license' in /var/www/ecoprintq.com.br/public_html/portal/intranet/classes/Upload.php on line 40

Warning: copy(0): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/ecoprintq.com.br/public_html/portal/intranet/classes/ManipularArquivos.php on line 23
```

Já coloquei os seguintes comandos no código do php

```
chmod("arquivo",750);
chmod("arquivo",755);
```

Tentaram mudar a permissão manualmente, pelo filezilla, e também não ouve sucesso.

Existe alguma outra alternativa??

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que dar permissão no diretório 'upload/PaperCutMF15-Pet Center Comercio e Participacoes S.A., BR.license' não somente no arquivo.

```
chmod 755 <upload-dir>
```

Comment: De preferencia pesquise se já existe respostas no site, pois se não ficam várias perguntas sobre o mesmo assunto e espalhadas, o ideial é favorecer as respostas e perguntas existentes que resolvem o assunto das duplicatas.

Comment: Esse "arquivo" seria arquivo php, ou a pasta com o arquivo?

Comment: tenta fazer o seguinte:

Comment: Acessa o servidor via linha de comando. Vai até o diretório que está a pasta "upload". Ai digita `chmod 755 -R upload`